# Wrap a field in html from template

Tags: 7, nodes

I have an *Article* content type that has `related_news` field. It displays inside the article text as a box.

In `node--article.tpl.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
     hide($content['comments']);
     hide($content['links']);
     hide($content['field_addthis']);    
     print render($content);
?>
```

I found that I can hide the `related_news` field using `hide` as:

```
hide($content['field_related_news']);
```

Is there any function like `hide` that could able to wrap the that field in custom *HTML* like `<div class="custom">...</div>`?

I tried the following:

```
//$content['field_related_news'] = "***". $content['field_related_news']."***";
```

But it causes to hide the field from the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily achieve that in your node file by using the [`field_view_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function and hiding it from the default `render($content)`.

To do that just set the display options in your custom content type to hide the title or whatever you want and put the following php code in your template:

```
<?php $related = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_related_news'); ?>
<div class="custom"><?php print render($related); ?></div>
```

Don't forget that you will need to hide your field in the `render($content)` otherwise you will see it twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating field tpl file.

Refer [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)

Create tpl file named as **field--field_related_news.tpl.php**